# How do I put one shader on top of another in cycles? Mix Shader doesn't work

Tags: materials

I have two shaders:
[image]
[image]
I need to put the second material on top of first material

Comment: use it as a mask (as factor) in a Mix Shader, if it doesn't work please share your file

Comment: how to use it as mask, sorry

Comment: could you please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or a platform like workupload

Comment: here it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=bgOQBQzX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/bgOQBQzX/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plug the *Color* output of the first node group into the *Factor* of the *Mix Shader*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked